# Magic number in R

Tags: r

How to find a magic number in R?
Example: 1729

- Find the sum of digits of the given number.`1 + 7 + 2 + 9` = `19`
- Reverse of digit sum output.  Reverse of `19` is `91`,
  `19 X 91` = `1729`
- So, `1729` is a magic number.

Comment: Perhaps a better fit for https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking for. Please provide more information.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  This looks like a problem from project euler.

Comment: @Aramis7d I am given any number, now how can i find out whether the number is a magic number or not on R. I have given an example with the number 1729 for your convenience. Did u get my question now?

Comment: @dvantwisk Trying out with a long process by converting the number to string and then using strsplit to extract each number. It's a long process. Looking for an optimal solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be like below:

```
num = 1729
sum_of_digits <- sum(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(num), split = ""))))
rev_of_sum_of_digits <- as.numeric(paste(rev(strsplit(as.character(sum_of_digits),"")[[1]]),collapse=""))

ifelse(rev_of_sum_of_digits * sum_of_digits == num, "Magic Number!", "Not a Magic Number!")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot buddy !!! (y)

Comment: Just one more question:         [[1]]),collapse=""))      << can you please explain this part???

Comment: `[[1]]` gives you the first element; `collapse`is an optional character string to separate the results (for more detail refer `?paste`). BTW if it solved your problem then you should accept it as the 'correct answer' as it'll help others in case they face similar issue in future :)

Comment: Yes, it was typo ;)

Comment: @Biswagourab please consider accepting this answer if it helped by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer